# Validation accuracy jumps badly between 0 and 1

Tags: cross-validation, prediction, dataset, validation

#### Issue:

My validation accuracy jumps between 0% and 100%.
This seems fairly implausible to me because the predictions are between two classes only and I am validating on full valSet (41802 records) each epoch. I doubt that a model which just started learning gets 100% accuracy on one epoch and then 0% accuracy the next epoch. 
[image]
[image]

#### Code samples:

I am validating on the full valSet per epoch. 
This is achieved by using  `validation_steps = {steps for full validation file}` and `dataset = dataset.repeat(numEpochsTrainSet)`

all my datasets are produced with the following code

```
def modelDataset(sourcepath, badgesize, repeat = False, repeatCount = 15):
    #get all files
    list = os.listdir(sourcepath)
    pathfiles = [sourcepath+x for x in list]

    #get metrics
    rows_per_file = count_lines(sourcepath+"0.data")
    number_of_files = len(list)
    total_rows = (rows_per_file * number_of_files)
    # get number of steps per Epoch
    epochs = number_of_files
    if  epochs == 1 and repeat:
        epochs = repeatCount
    elif epochs == 1:
        badgesize = rows_per_file
    steps_per_epoch = int(rows_per_file / badgesize) # 2000 badges per epoch   
    # model interleaved dataset
    dataset = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(pathfiles).interleave(lambda x:
        tf.data.TextLineDataset(x).map(parse_csv, num_parallel_calls=4),
        cycle_length=4, block_length=counter+1))
    if epochs != 1 or epochs != repeatCount:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=badgesize)
    if repeat:
        dataset = dataset.repeat(repeatCount)
        #dataset = dataset.cache().repeat(repeatCount)
    dataset = dataset.batch(badgesize)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)  # prefetch one batch
    return dataset, steps_per_epoch, epochs, badgesize

# generate dataset
valSet, valSteps, maxValEpochs, valBadgeSize = modelDataset(valPath, 1, True, maxTrainEpochs) 
# check if dataset is modeled correctly
print(f"number valSteps {valSteps}, maxepochs {maxValEpochs}, badgesize {valBadgeSize}") 
for elem in valSet:
  print(elem)
```

The output looks fine to me:
[image]

finally, the model is fit like the following:

```
model.fit(trainSet, 
    epochs = epochs, 
    steps_per_epoch = trainSteps, 
    shuffle = True, 
    validation_data = valSet, 
    validation_steps = valSteps, # how many batches do you want to validate on, NOT how many records
    class_weight=classDistr,
    verbose = verbose, 
    callbacks = [tensorboard,reduce_lr])#,cp_callback])
```

#### Issue assumptions

I would expect such validation results in one of the following scenarios:

- I am only validating on one record per epoch
- The validation Data is inconsistent with the train data
- The validation data contains labels of all the same class

I already tried to exclude those assumption with the following steps:

- I checked the source data csv file which looks fine, it has 41802 records
- In between those val_accuracies there are some which suggest against a validation on only one record:
  [image]
- output of `print(valset[0])` looks fine
- I found out that val-batchsize = train-batchsize so I adjusted te code but it did not make any difference

Comment: Obligatory reading: [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312780/why-is-accuracy-not-the-best-measure-for-assessing-classification-models/312787#312787).

Comment: In the end I will not use the model's class prediction but access its probability for each class. I think, that's what you suggested?

Comment: Yes. :) A rule of thumb: accuracy as metric is usually over-simplifying things. Also in cases of erratic behaviour off the bat: lower the learning rate, check the scales of the input data and add regularisation.

Comment: I Checked on those things. But I think in this case it is more sort of a bug. My Model seems to learn something but in this case it looks like a Bug